# How to show custom print/paginated preview(with Page Boxes) using Javascript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, dhtml

I need to show a print preview(Scrollable in single page) of the HTML content.

Please read the following carefully and suggest me the solution for the same.

The input will be a **dynamic raw data**(content can be huge), **Can we apply some standard custom CSS or javascript** and show the print preview of the content in the page.T**he print preview should have margins(spaces) in all sides and should look like the contents are placed in page boxes.**

Assume that the raw data has 200 lines, the print preview is going to show 50 lines/page,

Now the first page in print preview will have 50 lines and when the user scrolls the page, the second page will be shown with line from 51-100 and so on. In other words, the **margin space, height and width** of the page is fixed and  outcome should be like texts printed on a papers, not as web page.

Thanks in advance,
Chandra

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be either impossible or really, really difficult to achieve because there is no native, cross-browser zooming functionality that could help you with this goal.

Also, necessary information (like the printer's page size and margins) is not accessible from within the browser.

I would have users use the browser's built-in print preview instead.

Comment: I would like to add one more thing on this, assume that height of the page and width of the page , margin spaces are hard-coded. It does not required to bring from the printer. Only the number of pages should be a dynamic one based on the volume of the content.

Comment: @user I don't think it's going to work even then. The technical means simply aren't there. The browser's built-in print preview really is the way to go

Comment: Main aim is, user should feel the real look of the content printed in a paper.  Page alignments and breaking the contents into pages show the user with real feel of print preview is the aim.

Comment: @user sorry, I'm pretty sure this isn't going to work. You can set up a simple style sheet that will try to create the print effect for pre-defined HTML content, but it's cumbersome and likely to break, because as said there are factors outside the page's control.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly your question but:

I suppose you can create a page with using margin and padding and line-height to modify the content of the page. Also you link a css file with [media="print"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html), `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="foo.css">`

Then you make several print preview from your browser to test the appearance. When it's ok, you can add an iframe in your preview page which link the print page.

Comment: There's no way to accurately predict what the browser will do when it actually prints the page on a real printer.  You don't know (for example) whether a user has A4 or US Letter paper in the printer!

Comment: Can mention for what page size is the preview, or make several previews for the most popular page sizes.

Comment: Assume that height of the page and width of the page , margin spaces are hard-coded. It does not required to bring from the printer. Only the number of pages should be a dynamic one based on the volume of the content

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be a 'true' preview, but just give the user an idea of what the page will look like printed, you can use a print stylesheet.

i think this article can be a good guide: http://css-tricks.com/css-tricks-finally-gets-a-print-stylesheet/

once you have made your print stylesheet, you can just use jquery to switch stylesheets on your html content at the push of a button.

Comment: Print stylesheet can be the solution, if that can give real feel of page alignments as they will be printed in a paper(with all margin setup). As i mentioned, the content will be dynamic, only the CSS/Javascript can decide on the alignments. No hard-coded alignment changes can be done in the HTML files. Please suggest.

Comment: i edited the answer, with this technique you can edit the appearance of the html using css. i hope it helps.